# Multiple charts in an report for a specific column value

Tags: dynamic, graph, reporting-services, charts

I need to display multiple charts in an SSRS-Report. With multiple charts i don't mean multiple series in one chart area - i mean for each value a new chart area with an own chart. I don't know if this is possible but i'll give it a try :).

The data source is a table containing multiple rows and columns. One column contains a value containing the material no. Now i need to create a new chart for each material no. in this data table. The whole thing should look like this:

[image]

The number in the brackets is the material no. As you see i need to create one own chart for each material no. Is this possible?

Important: The material no. can exist multiple times in the data table but only one chart should be displayed for one material no. The values which belong to the specific material no. will be aggregated

**Update #1:**

First a screenshot showing the data the data source returns:

[image]
The expression for the hiding looks like this:

*Table 1*

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2) <> 0 AND (RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 3) <> 0, False, True)
```

*Table 2*

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2) = 0, False, True)
```

*Table 3*

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 3) = 0, False, True)
```

Here is a screenshot of the three tables inside the report.
[image: Three tables]

All three tables display the material no. They are all bound to the same data source with the row visibility expression posted aboth. The group expression for the row looks like this (typeMaterial is the column yieldTypeMaterial):

[image]
[image]

At the end, it results in this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this by putting the chart in table list and group the row by "Material No." and design the chart as per your requirement. By this, 1 chart will be displayed per row, but not as per your screenshot.

(I think below given is not a great idea, but we can try that).

I guess, to display as per your screenshot take 3 different tables, place them side-by-side and write filter conditions such that to hide some rows in table1(Ex. Display row no.'s in "table1" 1,4,7,10), display some rows in table2(2,5,8,11) and in Table3(3,6,9,12) as described in [this answer about faking multiple columns with tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882784/ssrs-how-to-continue-data-to-next-column/10890383#10890383).

Use below expressions for 3 Tables:

Table1

=iif((RunningValue(Fields!TypeMaterial.Value ,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 
2) <> 0 AND (RunningValue(Fields!TypeMaterial.Value ,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 
3) <> 0, False, True)

Table2

=iif((RunningValue(Fields!TypeMaterial.Value ,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 
2) = 0, False, True)

Table3

=iif((RunningValue(Fields!TypeMaterial.Value ,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 
3) = 0, False, True)

Comment: It don't has to look like in the screenshot. I just posted it to make clear what i mean :). What exactly is the table list? Can't find it in the SSRS toolbox and never heard of it relating to SSRS.

Comment: its nothing but the detail row (2nd row when we drag and drop table to design area).

Comment: Okay, got it - and it's working the way it should, BUT i discovered a "problem" with my data source for using this way: As you see in the picture i have to display a column for several months / weeks which are displayed in the x-axis. So the data source contains for example five rows with one and the same material no. for different weeks. When i use your approach, which is a really good 'workaround' , i have some material no. displayed more than once because of the fact that for example row one to five contain the same material no. I hope you can follow me

Comment: Have u grouped the table with material no.? Actually it should not be done as parent grouping, it should be row grouping. If possible send me the screenshot of it. So we can investigate the issue.

Comment: That's the same expression i am using for the first table?!

Comment: I have edited the answer. Look at it you have to change the visibility expressions for 3 tables as shown in answer.

Comment: Sexy! Works! Thank you very much :) - nice way to solve this! Never tought of going this way!