# How do I get my 2 columned report to do an actual page break and not just break to next column?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a thin table that is displayed in 2 columns.

```
Group 1
           |  Col1 Col2
Col1 Col2  |  data data 
data data  |  data data
data data  |  data data
data data  |  data data
...
```

when it gets to the end of the group and it is in the left column it "pagebreaks" to the next column so I get mixed groups on one page.

```
           |  Group 2
Col1 Col2  |  
data data  |  Col1 Col2
data data  |  data data
           |  data data
...
```

I have the tablix properties of my table set to page break after.
No other page break options seem to do anything.
How can I get my groups to always start on a new page and not in a new column?

Comment: You can fake multiple column output as described in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882784/ssrs-how-to-continue-data-to-next-column/10890383#10890383) so that page breaks on groups work properly.