# SQL Server Report Builder List expanding right and across

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

How to configure Report Builder List component to expand right and across?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: have you tried toggle view property?

Comment: It looks like you want the results to appear in two **columns**. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882784/ssrs-how-to-continue-data-to-next-column) should have what you're looking for, try using the 'fake multi-column' answer from Chris Lätta.

Comment: Thanks, it seams that will do the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882784/ssrs-how-to-continue-data-to-next-column):

On the Detail row of the first table, for the Visibility-Hidden property:

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2) = 1, False, True)
```

On the Detail row of the second table, for the Visibility-Hidden property:

```
=iif((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2) = 1, True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me, placing here for future reference.  The Report > Columns property  and hacks were a no go.
Using Power BI Report Builder (not SSRS, not PBI Desktop :)
[08-Horizontal Table Report](https://sqlserverbi.blog/08-horizontal-table-report/)