# Display data from table in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to achieve something in SSRS but not able to do so. I have around 3000 records in my table, but when I try to Preview that in SSRS report it is taking 103 pages to display. I tried to have two tables on the same page pointing to same dataset, but one table shows odd records and the other table shows even records with the help of rownumber(). With this I reduced my pages to 27.

I want the data to be displayed serially in one table, and when it reaches the end of the page it should transfer the next record to another table on the same page. I am attaching a table that I want to include in my report.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS - How to continue data to next column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882784/ssrs-how-to-continue-data-to-next-column)

Comment: It is not helpful. I tried and saved in PDF but it is not showing the expected output as above.

Comment: Hi, So I am able to get the columns on the same page as my requirement. But there is no header for the columns. Can anyone suggest what we should do for that? Also, there are spacing between the first and last columns. Can you see the spacing between column ROW and A and also between column C and D. 
How can I solve that?

ROW A B C  D  4  X Y Z  1
1  X Y Z  1  5  X Y Z  1
2  X Y Z  1  6  X Y Z  1
3  X Y Z  1

Answer (score 0):

Alter the white outer space in design view to the minimum.
Go into report properties and select columns , amend value to 2.

Comment: Note that the HTML renderer doesn't show multi-column reports, so it will display as one column. You need to render either to PDF or a printer to see multi-columns properly.

Comment: It is not helpful. I tried and saved in PDF but it is not showing the expected output as above.

Comment: Hi, So I am able to get the columns on the same page as my requirement. But there is no header for the columns. Can anyone suggest what we should do for that?

Comment: try microsoft at:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-row-and-column-headers-on-multiple-pages-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017